# How to round values of the index in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to round the index values of a pandas dataframe with the name results, such that they do not have any decimal values. I use the followin code that I took from here [Round columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247763/round-columns-in-pandas-dataframe). So basically I have a column with the name "set_timeslot" and I would like to round its values and then use it as an index

```
cols = ['set_timeslots']
results[cols]= results [cols].round(0)
results.set_index('set_timeslots', inplace=True)
```

However, I still get a decimal value as you can see in the screenshot[image]
Do you know what I have to do in order to get rid of the decimal values? I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need round and convert to integers add [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
results[cols]= results [cols].round(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't use `pandas.DataFrame.round()` in this scenario because the `round` module is used for the `trimming` of `decimal` points. let's take our `case` only.

```
# Import all-Important Libraries
import pandas as pd 

# Reproduced Sample 'set_timeslots'
results = pd.DataFrame({
    'set_timeslots':[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
})

# Declaration of 'cols' variable for storing 'set_timeslots' column
cols = ['set_timeslots']

# Print result
results[cols]
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
    set_timeslots
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   4.0
4   5.0
```

```
# Implementation of 'round' module:-
results[cols] = results[cols].round(0)

# Print result after round function
results
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
    set_timeslots
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   4.0
4   5.0
```

#### Appropriate Solution:-

So, for the conversion of `set_timeslots` from `decimal` to `int` we can use `pandas.DataFrame.astype()` Module.

`Code` for above mention scenario was stated below:-

```
# Implementation of 'astype(int)' function
results[cols] = results[cols].astype(int)

# Print result after the Conversion
results
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
    set_timeslots
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

As you can see we have achieved our desired `output` which is to remove `decimal` points from `set_timeslots` `column`. and Hope this `Solution` helps you in the clarification of `round()` function and `astype()` function.

> To Learn more about `pandas.DataFrame.round()`:- [Click Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) 
> To Learn more about `pandas.DataFrame.astype()`:- [Click Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Comment: Hmm, so it is not same like my answer answered more like 1hour before?